# 401 on URL authentication with Spring boot & Spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Springboot with Spring security.
With below configuration,

```
http.csrf()
    .disable().authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/myHome").authenticated();
```

I am able to access myHome page by adding Basic Auth header in POSTMAN.

But accessing the with URL is giving 401.

http://testUser:testPassword@localhost:8080/myHome

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security's Basic Authentication requires that the `username:password` be a Base64 encoded string in the header.

```
Base64.encode("username:password");
```

Using `http://user:password@domain/` is not secure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped.
Is there any reference on need of header? (& which says URL way is not supported)

Comment: You can read the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.M5/reference/html5/